# how to change permissions for all text channels with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command to change the permissions on all text channels
but it does not work

```
@bot.command()
async def close_all(ctx):
  overwrite = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
  overwrite.send_messages = False
  overwrite.read_messages = False
  ctx.get_channel = ctx.message.server
  await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrite)
```

i also tried to put `guild` but it say `AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'channel'`

```
@bot.command()
async def close_all(ctx):
  await ctx.guild.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Guild` has no attribute `channel`, but it does have `channels` which is a list of all channels in the guild that you can loop through:

```
for chan in guild.channels:
    await chan.set_permissions(cts.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
```

Comment: but now i have another problem

`discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: guild is a required argument that is missing.`

i just edit the code:













`@bot.command()
 async def close_all(ctx, *, guild: discord.Guild):
   for chan in guild.channels:
     await chan.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)`