# Hide all channels except one for everyone except some roles discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I hide all channels except one (the one can be excluded with role id or name) except for admin with discord.py.

```
hide all channels except one (by making it private) with a command
Return all channels back to normal with a command
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you meant channel id and not "role id", given such you can make every channel hidden by setting the permissions for @everyone "read messages" to False in every channel, except for the excluded channel.
I'm personally using discord.app_commands.CommandTree so it looks like this:

```
@tree.command(name='hideall')
async def hideall(interaction: discord.Interaction, exception: discord.TextChannel):
    for chan in interaction.guild.channels: #for every channel in server
        if chan.id != exception.id: #excludes excepted channel
            await chan.set_permissions(interaction.guild.default_role, read_messages=False)
            #overwrites read_messages permission to False for @everyone i.e set to private
```

If you want the excluded channel to shown to everyone (if it was not already), you can change the permission for that specific channel:

```
@tree.command(name='hideall')
async def hideall(interaction: discord.Interaction, exception: discord.TextChannel):
    for chan in interaction.guild.channels:
        if chan.id == exception.id:　#if it is the channel
            await chan.set_permissions(interaction.guild.default_role, read_messages=True) #set to unprivate
        else:
            await chan.set_permissions(interaction.guild.default_role, read_messages=False) #if other channel, private
```

If you want it for other roles (instead of @everyone), you can add `role: discord.Role` in the command (asking command user for role input) and change `interaction.guild.default_role` to `role` or whatever you define discord.Role as.

However, this is very hard to reverse. You either have to change the permissions of the channels manually or if you want to make it a command, you might need to store the channels that already had the read_messages permissions for @everyone as False and exclude those from `set_permissions` in the reverse command.

(Command1: Store channel id of channel that already had read_messages permission set to False in a file
Command2: If channel does not match any channel id(s) in file, set permission, read_messages back to True)

Here's how I did the second command:

```
@tree.command(name='returnall')
async def returnall(interaction: discord.Interaction, role: discord.Role=None):
  if role == None:
    role = interaction.guild.default_role
  for chan in interaction.guild.channels: #for every channel in server
    for line in open('filename.txt', 'r'):
      if chan.id == int(line): #check if channel id is in the file
        await chan.set_permissions(role, view_channel=False)
        break
    else: #if channel id is not in file
      await chan.set_permissions(role, view_channel=True)
```

Editing first command:

```
with open("filename.txt",'r+') as file:
  file.truncate(0) #clears file
for chan in interaction.guild.channels: #for every channel in server
  if chan.permissions_for(role).view_channel == False: #if channel is originally private
    with open('filename.txt', 'a') as f:
      categorycheck = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.categories, id=chan.id)
      if categorycheck == None: #if it is not a category
        f.write(str(chan.id) + '\n') #write channel id in file
for chan in interaction.guild.channels: #for every channel in server
        if chan.id != exception.id: #excludes excepted channel
            await chan.set_permissions(interaction.guild.default_role, read_messages=False)
            #overwrites read_messages permission to False for @everyone i.e set to private
```

Things to note:
My command returns all of the channels to unprivate before putting the channels that are to be privated to private (Showing privated channels to everyone before putting them back)
This is probably not the best way to do this but it is one that works.

[Reference for overwriting the permissions of all channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60318856/how-to-change-permissions-for-all-text-channels-with-discord-py)

[Reading text files](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-read-text-file/) and [Writing text files](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-write-text-file/)